# Tree: Level order Traversal using queue

Tags: c, tree

I wrote codes that traversing tree using queue, but dequeue function below generates error, Is there any problem with `head = p->next` ? 
I cannot figure out why this part is wrong.

```
void Levelorder(void) {
node *tmp, *p;


if (root == NULL) return;

tmp = root;
printf("The level order is :\n");

while (tmp != NULL) {

    printf("%d, ", tmp->data);
    if (tmp->left) {
        enqueue(tmp->left);
    }
    if (tmp->right) {
        enqueue(tmp->right);
    }
    tmp = dequeue();
}

return;
}

void enqueue(node *p) {
if (head == NULL) {
    head = p;
}
else {
    tail->next = p;
}
tail = p;
p->next = NULL;
tail->next = NULL;

return;
}

node* dequeue(void) {
node *p;
p = head;
head = p->next;


if (head == NULL) {
    tail == NULL;
}

return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of your while loop is:

```
while (tmp != NULL) {
```

So it will terminate only when `dequeue` returns `NULL` here:

```
    tmp = dequeue();
```

But this cannot happen, when looking at the implementation of dequeue:

```
node* dequeue(void) {
    node *p;
    p = head;
```

Here, `p` is dereferenced:

```
    head = p->next;

    if (head == NULL) {
        tail == NULL;
    }
```

And here, `p` is returned:

```
    return p;
}
```

To return a `NULL` pointer and leave your while-loop, `p` had to be `NULL` here. But then, a `NULL` pointer would be dereferenced with `head = p->next;` before, which would lead to a segmentation fault (UB in terms of the C-language).

You should check at the beginning of your dequeue-function if `head` is a NULL pointer and return NULL in that case:

```
node* dequeue(void) {
    node *p;
    if (!head)
         return NULL;

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your hep. but still can't get the idea of deferenced wit ' head =p ->next' . How p that contains NULL pointer could be deferenced by ' head = p->next' ?

Comment: @Ezerk It cannot, that why the program crashes at that point. Perhaps you are irritated, that you have no output at all then; that's because `printf()` usually line-buffers its output on terminal devices.

Comment: Thanks your comment.